# Is it possible to show a custom variable in a lightning-record-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-components

I have this lightning form that shows fields from a custom object. I need to add a new line under the last one that shows custom data that is calculated when the lwc is opened and is only stored
in JS variables and not in any object field.

Is it possible to add new fields in the same style of the others that show data from a JS variable?

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-section__content">
    <lightning-record-form object-api-name='Forecast__c' record-id={forecastId} fields={forecastMonthlyBudgetFields} columns="3" mode="readonly" >
    </lightning-record-form>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But only before or after the `lightning-record-form` fields.

Add normal HTML using the SLDS CSS classes documented in [Form Element](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/) and use the [lightning-formatted-*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example) components to present the data value from a property of your LWC class e.g.:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked">
    <div class="slds-form-element__label">Approval Status</div>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-form-element__static">
            <lightning-formatted-text value={approvalStatus}>
            </lightning-formatted-text>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get a good layout match, you can inspect the CSS classes generated by the `lightning-record-form` and check the SLDS documentation and apply those.

(The platform really encourages you to use custom fields - that can include formulas and aggregates - for pretty much every value. That then makes presentation and editing easy, and ensures the values can also be used in e.g. reports.)